# Python - getpass2 to python3 configuration problems

Tags: python, pycharm, getpass

So lately, i've been working on my osu! Map Downloader, which i've posted about today.. too. So, my second problem is that when i try to create a hidden password, i can't. Well, i'm sure you know the library getpass. If not this is it: [getpass2](https://github.com/guoruibiao/getpass2)
. Well, it is very helfpul when you're trying to make a hidden password. And well, it's a bit old, and it is strictly based on python2. I've been trying for hours now to change a few keywords in the source files in order for them to work. So, here they are:

```
import sys
import importlib
importlib.reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

I've used the default importlib library for `reload`, which was helpful and worked. But then came `setdefaultencoding`. It is strictly a python2 keyword, and i've got no idea what to do next. I also tried using py2to3 which didn't work, because.. apparently it didn't detect anything wrong with the **init**.py file which is where this little script is in.
Any ideas?